Confidence intervals ODE ridge regression
i want to find confidence intervals for a least squares loss which is L2 regularized. I have only found something for linear problems, but in my case i want to estimate ordinary differential equation parameters (so highly nonlinear). Has anyone ever dealt with the same problem?

Please spell out your acronyms.

You mean in the text? Should be fine now :)

I’m not clear on what you mean. You have a differential equation and you want to estimate its parameters from data? Where does the regularization come into play? Do you want to regularized the estimates of the parameters?

S i have the likelihood which defines how well my data is fitted by the current parameters. Since i have an additional degree of freedom in my parameters i want to regularize them with ridge regression. So my loss function is likelihood + regularization term
